# After maven project imported in Intellij IDE all java option missing

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using iIntelli IDEA ultimate 15. I created a maven project from console as: mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.maum.spring -DartifactId=CounterWebAppMasum -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false

When I import it in IDE all Java option missing such as make new package, class, etc. How can I bring Java options after import maven project in iIntelli IDEA ultimate 15? Please check the picture :-

[image]

## UPDATED information.

I created directory structure and add a java file. But it doesn't recognize as java project. Check the following pic:-

[image]

Comment: Right click on pom and try to Click Maven->Reimport dependencies. If this does not work try to go to the project settings and choose Java facet

Comment: the Mark Directory as is available in the screen shot

Answer (score 1):

I think its because IntelliJ has missed that its a Java Project.

Right click on the Java directory and select 'Mark Directory As' from the context menu, then Select "source root"

You might have to manually set the type in the project module settings, press F4

Comment: No such option "Mark Directory As". Also if I press F4 nothing happens. I manually created directory and java file. But it doesn't recognize it s java project. Please check updated pic the question.

Comment: `Mark Directory As` is in your screenshots, third from bottom when you right-click on the folder